# local class incompatible: stream classdesc

Tags: java, hadoop, serialization, mapreduce, apache-pig

```
test = FOREACH data { a = (IsNumeric(age) ? (int)age : null); GENERATE (a IS NULL ? NULL : 0) AS age_bucket:int;};
```

age:chararray in the data. the script fails with error :

Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2997: Unable to recreate exception from backed error: Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Problem while configuring reduce plan.
        at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigGenericMapReduce$Reduce.setup(PigGenericMapReduce.java:351)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:168)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:627)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:389)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Deserialization error: org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.UnaryComparisonOperator; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -1153715670674229029, local class serialVersionUID = -4935333078211151221
        at org.apache.pig.impl.util.ObjectSerializer.deserialize(ObjectSerializer.java:62)

Comment: I can help you with this, have you solved?

Comment: can you please help ?

Comment: Well this is definitely a serialization problem, so let me check out

Comment: Ok, first. did you use `using` statement to define a structure?? I mean the problem i think is that when you're doing the transformation operation, Pig is not able to define a value type for the `age` variable. this value must be a `atom: single value` but it seems like Pig is not correct with that.

Comment: If you don't use the `using as` statement, you're basically telling to pig to LOAD the function to expect a plain text file that is `tab` delimited. So, With no schema provided. the file will be referenced by a position because no name is defined.

Comment: You can use the `describe` statement to return the `schema of a relation`. In this case, you can use `describe` to see what is the schema of `data` variable.

Comment: 0


Thanks. I wrote a UDF instead to do all validation and filtering for age bucketing. Seems there was issue with the version of jar which I was using. I gave up on it. UDF in java was easier option.

Comment: ok, I'm glad you solve the problem